# How is the minimum of a set of IID random variables distributed?

Tags: distributions, random-variable, extreme-value

If $X_1, ..., X_n$ are independent identically-distributed random variables, what can be said about the distribution of $\min(X_1, ..., X_n)$ in general?

Comment: Mathematical answer or numerical? Your question is very general. For a fast algorithm see the article here: https://medium.com/@mike.roweprediger/density-of-the-minimum-of-n-random-variables-on-a-lattice-45583cc0c2d0 but I'm not sure if that is the question.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If the cdf of $X_i$ is denoted by $F(x)$, then the cdf of the minimum is given by $1-[1-F(x)]^n$.

Answer (score 91):

If the CDF of $X_i$ is denoted by $F(x)$, then the CDF of the minimum is given by $1-[1-F(x)]^n$.

**Reasoning:** given $n$ random variables, the probability $P(Y\leq y) = P(\min(X_1\dots X_n)\leq y)$ implies that at least one $X_i$ is smaller than $y$.

The probability that at least one $X_i$ is smaller than $y$ is equivalent to one minus the probability that all $X_i$ are greater than $y$, i.e. $P(Y\leq y) = 1 - P(X_1 \gt y,\dots, X_n \gt y)$.

If the $X_i$'s are independent identically-distributed, then the probability that all $X_i$ are greater than $y$ is $[1-F(y)]^n$. Therefore, the original probability is $P(Y \leq y) = 1-[1-F(y)]^n$.

**Example**: say $X_i \sim \text{Uniform} (0,1)$, then intuitively the probability $\min(X_1\dots X_n)\leq 1$ should be equal to 1 (as the minimum value would always be less than 1 since $0\leq X_i\leq 1$ for all $i$). In this case $F(1)=1$ thus the probability is always 1.

Comment: This site supports Markdown syntax for editing, and also LATEX for mathematical expressions. Further information can be found here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/editing-help.

Comment: Thanks for providing the reasoning. I had a problem with non-identically-distributed variables, but the minimum logic still applied well :)

Comment: I think that answer 1-(1-F(x))^n is correct in special cases. Special cases is condition that pmf of r.v. is based on a formula for domain of r.v. If it be different in various parts of domain above mentioned formula deviates a little from actual simulation results.

Comment: Can anything be said about the mean and the standard deviation?

Answer (score 26):

Rob Hyndman gave the easy exact answer for a fixed n.  If you're interested in asymptotic behavior for large n, this is handled in the field of [extreme value theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theory).  There is a small family of possible limiting distributions; see for example the first chapters of [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=3ZKmAAAAIAAJ&q=leadbetter+and+lindgren&dq=leadbetter+and+lindgren&hl=en&ei=z7ZFTPPFH9T-nAfa58HaAw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA).

Comment: My opinion is that this book is THE book about extrem value theory