# Conditional Expectation for Probability Distribution

Tags: probability, exponential-distribution, conditional-expectation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How is the minimum of a set of random variables distributed?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220/how-is-the-minimum-of-a-set-of-random-variables-distributed)

I have two RVs from the same distribution (exponential distribution with parameter λ). How do I calculate E(min|min>x)? I know how to get E(X|X>x) but I specifically need X to be the smallest of the two RVs.

Comment: If you have the density function for the minimum, then it's exactly the same as doing the calculation for an arbitrary random variable, $X$. Are you asking how to derive the density of the minimum?

Comment: Sorry for confusion - yes, that is basically what I am asking.

Comment: This is a commonly asked question on here. See, for example, this thread: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220/how-is-the-minimum-of-a-set-of-random-variables-distributed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macro has pointed you at previous discussion of the distribution of the minimum. For your particular problem with exponentially distributed random variables it is even easier.

An exponential distribution is the time for the first occurrence of a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$ so the minimum of $n$ iid exponentially distributed random variables  is the time for the first occurrence of a Poisson process with rate $n\lambda$ and so is exponentially distributed with mean $\frac{1}{n\lambda}$.

But an exponential distribution is memoryless, so $E(\min | \min > x) = x+ \frac{1}{n\lambda}$.

In your particular question, $n=2$.