# How is the minimum of a random set of random variables distributed?

Tags: distributions, random-variable

If $X_1,...,X_N$ are independent and identically distributed exponential random variables, what can be said about the distribution of $\text{min}(X_1,...,X_N)$ when $N$ is *random* and modelled as a Poisson random variable?

Comment: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220/how-is-the-minimum-of-a-set-of-random-variables-distributed?rq=1

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the `[self-study]`
tag & read its [wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is really a duplicate of the linked thread, given the Poisson distribution of n.

Comment: No this question is not for course and it is not duplicated as In this case the $n$ is also random which is different from the other question that $n$ is fixed.

Comment: There might be an incorrect duplicate tag. The size of the sample $n$ is also random here, and modeled with a Poisson. This makes the problem different from the link provided as duplicate.

Comment: @ÄminPersialinen: Please check if my edits are correct. I also replaced the small $n$ by a $N$ to stress the fact that it is a random variable.

Comment: The poisson distribution puts positive mass on zero.  How is the min of an empty set of random variables defined?

Comment: I don't know how this happened -- I didn't VTC as duplicate, I VTC as self-study.

Comment: @AlexR. In the provided link, n is fixed and if you look at my question I considered the case that N is random as well. Thanks for the comment

Comment: First you'll need to define the minimum when $N=0$ (or use a shifted poisson distribution starting at $N=1$). 

The random $N$ doesn't add much: Given $N=n$, you get 
$P(\min(X_1,\cdots,X_N)\leq x | N=n)=1-[1-F(x)]^n$. Notice that the minimum of exponential random variables is exponentially distributed with parameter $\lambda= \lambda_1+\cdots\lambda_n$. 

Now just sum over:

$$P(\min(X_1,\cdots,X_N)\leq x) = \sum_{n\geq 0} [1-(1-F(x))^n ] P(N=n)$$

Comment: If the Poisson distribution allows n=0, then there are no samples in that draw.  Programmatically I would consider it as either an NA-padded mixture, or a draw that results in no samples added to the pool.  I like Alex's idea about shifting the Poisson distribution.