# How to fully estimate a probability density from only a sample of minimum values?

Tags: distributions, density-function, order-statistics, extreme-value, density-estimation

We are given a sample $\{ z_i \}$, $i=1,2,\ldots,N$, such that each value $z_i$ corresponds to the minimum of $n$ random variables $x$, i.e.,  $z = \min \{ x_1, x_2,\ldots,x_n \}$.

By means of elementary order statistics and the empirical distribution function $F_z$ of $z$, we can do $F_x = 1-(1-F_z)^{1/n}$ to obtain the CDF of $x$ (see https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/10072). However, since $z$ are minimum values, the sample $\{ z_i \}$ can hardly tell us anything about the right tail of the density, $P(x \rightarrow\infty)$.

**The question is:** how can we improve the elementary method stated above in order to be able to say something about the right tail of $P(x)$?

Comment: Assumption of symmetry of F_x may be an option. An assumption one may or may not be willing to make depending on context.

Comment: If $F_x$ is known to lie within a parametric family,
Maximum-Likelihood can be used to infer on it from the $z_i$ - even
with $n$ depending on $i$.  If instead no information about $F_x$ is
available, $F_x$ can only be poorly inferred from the $z_i$ for large
$n$ because very different $F_x$ lead to similar $F_z$.